# Neo4j handling date time values as different nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am importing a CSV file with financial data in it. How do I model the graph in such a way that the YEAR, MONTH, and DAY values are shown as three different nodes.

```
Created_Date,TransactionId
2017-10-17 12:37:00.287,1 
2018-03-15 02:00:48.930,2
```

I checked a few of documentation, and all of them helped me form just a single node.

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///filename.csv' as row
WITH apoc.date.parse(row.Created_Date, "ms", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS") AS ms
MERGE (d:Date {date: date(datetime({epochmillis: ms}))})
```

The structure I am looking for is more of **TransId - Year - Month - Date**. How do I manage to get this with the datetime library?

Comment: Can you describe your use case? Also, are you saying you want a relationship between year and month and another between month and date?

Comment: @cybersam I wish to filter this data using date, meaning there has to be 4 nodes and 4 relationship between: Year, Month, Day, TransId. A small use case is to analyse the nature of transaction over a period of time.

Comment: You can do filtering without creating separate nodes for the date components. What do you believe to be the benefits of your design over, say, just having 3 properties (for the date components) in each Transaction node?

Comment: @cybersam Yeah the design should always be made simple. I tweaked the code a bit to achieve a fair result. 
`LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///filename.csv' as row`
`WITH apoc.date.fields(LEFT(row.Created_Date, 10), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS val`
`MERGE (d:Date {year: val.years, month: val.months, day: val.days})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to parse the DateTime values and store them as properties to a Node.

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///filename.csv' as row
WITH apoc.date.fields(LEFT(row.Created_Date, 10), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS val
MERGE (d:Date {year: val.years, month: val.months, day: val.days})
```